# Transformation and rotation by 90 degree

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be the rotation by 90 degrees about the point
$(4,3) .$ Compute $T\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}{x} \\ {y}\end{array}\right]\right)$ for any real numbers $x, y \in \mathbb{R} .$.

I know the rotation matrix associated with 90 degree transformation. But I am not able to understand this question well. So after rotation point $(4,3)$ goes to $(-3,4)$ ; geometrically I can see it.

Comment: What is that matrix ?

Comment: You then need to translate $(-3,4)$ back to $(4,3)$.

Comment: The question is not asking you to rotate the point $(4,3)$. It is asking you to rotate $(x,y)$ about it.

Comment: it is [0 -1, 1 0]

Comment: @S.SundaraNarasimhan so answer will become (-x +4 , y+3) right?

Comment: @mathsstudent I guess my earlier comment was wrong, please ignore it. Ted Shifrin has given the complete answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that we're rotating *about* the point $(4,3)$, not the origin. So you will not have a matrix representation for $T$ — it will not be a linear transformation. So here's the protocol: Start with a vector $\vec x$, subtract $(4,3)$. Now rotate the vector $\vec x-(4,3)$ through your $90^\circ$ angle, and then translate the result back by adding $(4,3)$.

Comment: Wow. As a non-english I didn't understand (and thus overlooked) this tiny "about" in "rotate about" as well as @Bernard before. "Rotating *around*" would have made it correctly in my ear, so... A definitive trap in a test for me...

Answer (score 3):

If you set the origin at $(4,3)$, the new coordinates $(x',y')$ of a point $(x,y)$  satisfy the equation
$$T(x',y')=(-y',x').$$
Now, we have $x'=x-4,\;y'=y-3$, so $(x,y)$ maps to $(3-y,x-4)$ (coordinates with origin at $(4,3)$), i.e. with coordinatesvwith origin at $(0,0)$: $(3-y+4,x-4+3)=(7-y,x-1)$.

In terms of matrices:
$$T(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&\phantom{-}0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\phantom{-}7\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
This is an *affine* transformation.

Comment: This isn't correct. What does your formula give for $T(4,3)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: You're. I overlooked we were in the new coordinate system for the result in function of $x$ and $y$. So easy to walk into a trap… I've fixed it. Thank you so much for pointing it!

Comment: Yes, now your solution is precisely what I sketched in mine earlier :)

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't seen it.  I must say I don't  think there are so may ways to address this problem.